# How to install Azure terratest module

Tags: go, terratest

I am getting the following error while installing azure module.

**code:**

```
package test

import (
    "testing"
    "github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-go/profiles/latest/cosmos-db/mgmt/documentdb"
    "github.com/gruntwork-io/terratest/modules/azure"
    "github.com/stretchr/testify/assert"
)

func TestTerraformAzureCosmosDBExample(t *testing.T) {
    foo
    boo
}
```

**Execution:**

```
C:\foo\boo>go test -v
# foo_test
foo_test.go:6:2: no required module provides package github.com/gruntwork-io/terratest/modules/azure; to add it:
        go get github.com/gruntwork-io/terratest/modules/azure
FAIL    foo_test [setup failed]
```

**Error:**

```
C:\foo\boo>go get github.com/gruntwork-io/terratest/modules/azure
# github.com/gruntwork-io/terratest/modules/azure
C:\foo\go\pkg\mod\github.com\gruntwork-io\terratest@v0.36.5\modules\azure\keyvault.go:139:50: too many arguments in call to "github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-go/services/keyvault/auth".NewAuthorizerFromFile
        have (string)
        want ()
C:\foo\go\pkg\mod\github.com\gruntwork-io\terratest@v0.36.5\modules\azure\resourcegroup.go:78:9: cannot use &rg (type *"github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-go/services/resources/mgmt/2020-10-01/resources".Group) as type *"github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-go/services/resources/mgmt/2020-06-01/resources".Group in return argument
C:\foo\go\pkg\mod\github.com\gruntwork-io\terratest@v0.36.5\modules\azure\resourcegroup.go:100:18: cannot use rg.Values() (type []"github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-go/services/resources/mgmt/2020-10-01/resources".Group) as type []"github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-go/services/resources/mgmt/2020-06-01/resources".Group in return argument
```

Can someone help me as to what changes required to get rid of this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting out from [this initial state](https://play.golang.org/p/WiDuzRP5BbX):

```
-- main.go --
package main

import (
    _ "github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-go/profiles/latest/cosmos-db/mgmt/documentdb"
    _ "github.com/gruntwork-io/terratest/modules/azure"
    _ "github.com/stretchr/testify/assert"
)

func main() {}
-- go.mod --
module example.com/m

go 1.17
```

---

First, run `go mod tidy` to fill in a complete (but perhaps incompatible) set of dependencies.

```
$ go mod tidy
go: finding module for package github.com/stretchr/testify/assert
go: finding module for package github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-go/profiles/latest/cosmos-db/mgmt/documentdb
go: finding module for package github.com/gruntwork-io/terratest/modules/azure
go: found github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-go/profiles/latest/cosmos-db/mgmt/documentdb in github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-go v55.6.0+incompatible
go: found github.com/gruntwork-io/terratest/modules/azure in github.com/gruntwork-io/terratest v0.36.5
go: found github.com/stretchr/testify/assert in github.com/stretchr/testify v1.7.0
go: finding module for package github.com/gofrs/uuid
go: found github.com/gofrs/uuid in github.com/gofrs/uuid v4.0.0+incompatible
```

---

Now try `go build`.

```
$ go build .
# github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-go/services/mysql/mgmt/2020-01-01/mysql
.gopath/pkg/mod/github.com/!azure/azure-sdk-for-go@v55.6.0+incompatible/services/mysql/mgmt/2020-01-01/mysql/models.go:346:2: undefined: azure.FutureAPI
…
```

It produces lots of errors, which isn't entirely unexpected: `azure-sdk-for-go` is on major version 55(!), which to me indicates a high rate of breaking changes. So probably this version of `terratest` was written against an older version, and has been broken by some intervening change.

---

To figure out which version `terratest` is written against, I can check [its `go.mod` file](https://github.com/gruntwork-io/terratest/blob/v0.36.5/go.mod). At `terratest` `v0.36.5`, it specifies

```
    github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-go v46.0.0+incompatible
```

So let's try that version:

```
$ go get -d github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-go@v46.0.0+incompatible
go: downloading github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-go v46.0.0+incompatible
go get: downgraded github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-go v55.6.0+incompatible => v46.0.0+incompatible
```

---

Now `go build` again:

```
$ go build .
.gopath/pkg/mod/github.com/!azure/azure-sdk-for-go@v46.0.0+incompatible/services/mysql/mgmt/2020-01-01/mysql/models.go:28:2: missing go.sum entry for module providing package github.com/satori/go.uuid (imported by github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-go/services/keyvault/mgmt/2016-10-01/keyvault); to add:
        go get github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-go/services/keyvault/mgmt/2016-10-01/keyvault@v46.0.0+incompatible
```

This is because I told `go get` to download a specific version of a *module*, but I actually need a set of *packages* from within that module — and I'm missing checksums for some of the dependencies of those packages. So I'll run `go mod tidy` to fix up the package graph again:

```
$ go mod tidy
go: downloading github.com/satori/go.uuid v1.2.0
```

And that does the trick:

```
$ go build .

$
```